# How to prevent email clients from removing media query like putsmail does?

Tags: responsive

I'm wondering if we can prevent email clients like Google, Yahoo, etc. from stripping out  tags from our HTML. I saw putsmail do that. So, I'm looking for similar way to escape email clients refactoring.

Comment: You can not prevent actions taken by client software. Client software can add, remove, modify, or block any content of a document they wish.